# CefCore compilation - failed

Tags: c++, c, compilation, chromium-embedded

I have problem with Cef compilation,
I'm getting always the same error while compiling.
exactly i'm getting OutOfMemory even if I'm doing this compilation on AWS Instance with 4TB of RAM.
I'm trying to fallow this guide: https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/MasterBuildQuickStart

The error is alway occuring on the penultimate step of compiling.

Is there someone who successfully compiled cef and can help me with this?

Comment: 4TB of RAM? Really?

Comment: @S.M. Yes that was x1e.32xlarge instance from AWS with 3,904 GiB of RAM.

Comment: I'm not sure that 4TB are available to the build environment.

Comment: I'd suggest searching/asking on https://magpcss.org/ceforum/index.php as the CEF maintainer doesn't monitor stackoverflow questions to my knowledge.